# How to select data between two characters

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Want select data from string which always start with `*` symbol and end with `*` OR `|`. For example, it must work for both strings: `232323*123456*123512`  and `232323*123456|123512`.

I try to parse like this :

```
declare @s varchar(max) = '232323*123456*123512'
select parsename(replace(@s, '*', '.'), 2)
```

But this one works only with `232323*123456*123512`.
Need parser which will work with `'232323*123456|123512'` also.
Response must be for both strings : `123456`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use another `Replace` on top of your existing `replace` to replace both the symbols to `'.'`

```
DECLARE @S VARCHAR(MAX) = '232323*123456|123512'

SELECT Parsename(Replace(Replace(@S, '*', '.'), '|', '.'), 2) --123456
```

**Update:** to handle `.` replace the `.` with any other symbol do the parsing then finally replace the symbol with `.`

```
SELECT replace(Parsename(Replace(Replace(replace(@S,'.','~'), '*', '.'), '|', '.'), 2),'~','.') --12.34.56
```

Comment: thanks , can you tell me if string will be like 232323*12.34.56|123512  Response is NULL , can we avoid it ? And bring response : 12.34.56 ?

Answer (score 1):

You can try replacing both '*' and '|':

```
declare @s varchar(max) = '232323*123456|123512'
select parsename(replace(replace(@s, '|', '.'), '*', '.'), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is:

```
declare @s varchar(max) = '232323*123456|123512'
```

First replace all chars in order to have the same delimiters:

```
SET @s = REPLACE(@s, '|', '*')
```

Then select sub-string between first occurence of `*` and next occurence of `*`

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(@s, CHARINDEX('*', @s) + 1, CHARINDEX('*', @s, CHARINDEX('*', @s) + 1) - CHARINDEX('*', @s) - 1)
```